# how to view pdf in new window?

Tags: javascript, pdf

In crome this works fine but not in ie and safari.

```
newwin('data:application/pdf;base64,' + BASE64VARIABLE,600,600);

function newwin(url,w,h) {
     var win = window.open("","temp","width="+w+",height="+h+",menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,location=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=auto,resizable=yes");
     win.location.href = url;
     win.focus();
}
```

in both of the browser the windows open but no content is shown.
In safari it attempts to download the file.
This is a real ball buster and i dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of IE do not support the data: protocol - [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).
Some more information about IE can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Not sure about Safari